# Why can't I insert HTML images?

Tags: html

I am a beginner who is learning HTML recently. I put the same HTML file and image in the same folder as below, but only the image icon is displayed and does not print out. Please help me.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ko">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-wid">
        <title>Typing Text</title>
        <img src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/2889/2889312.png" alt= "img" width="1000", height="500">
        <link herf="typr.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="dynamic" class="ig-text">
             Learn To HTML
             
        </p>
        <p class="sm text" > LAilac
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ko">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-wid">
        <title>Typing Text</title>
        <img src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/2889/2889312.png" alt= "img" width="1000", height="500">
        <link herf="typr.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="dynamic" class="ig-text">
             Learn To HTML
             
        </p>
        <p class="sm text" > LAilac
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can’t reproduce the problem. The images display.

Answer (score 0):

Move the `<img>` tag inside the `<body>` tag. You placed it in the `<head>` section.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ko">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-wid">
    <title>Typing Text</title>
    
    <link herf="typr.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <img src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/2889/2889312.png" alt= "img" width="1000", height="500">
     <p id="dynamic" class="ig-text">
          Learn To HTML
          
     </p>
     <p class="sm text" > LAilac
     </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The specification for parsing HTML means that, despite the error, the img *is* actually in the body. While writing valid HTML is a good idea, this shouldn’t make any difference as to if the image displays or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ko">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-wid">
        <title>Typing Text</title>
        
        <link herf="typr.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
<img src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/2889/2889312.png" alt= "img" width="1000", height="500">
        <p id="dynamic" class="ig-text">
             Learn To HTML
             
        </p>
        <p class="sm text" > LAilac
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

The reason is because you didn't move your `<img>` tag inside the `<body>` tag.

Comment: The specification for parsing HTML means that, despite the error, the img *is* actually in the body. While writing valid HTML is a good idea, this shouldn’t make any difference as to if the image displays or not.